# Magento 2 : Upgrade Existing Custom Customer Attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, upgrade, custom

I have created custom customer attribute and use at registration process. Its working fine.

Now I want update attribute like - previously its `'required'=> false`. Now I want to set it as `'required'=> true`.

But don't know how to upgrade it using `UpgradeData.php`

Plz help to solve this.

I tried with below code -

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.6", "<")) 
        {
            /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

            /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->updateAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'netz_allowed', [
                'visible_on_front' => 1,
                'input' => 'select',
                'require' => true,          
                'source' => 'Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno',
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'netz_allowed')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_create','customer_account_edit']]);

            $attribute->save(); 
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
<?php
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
       $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

       $customerSetup->updateAttribute(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                'your_attribute_id',                    
                'required',
                true
            );


          $Attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute( \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'your_attribute_id');

        $Attribute->setData(
        'used_in_forms',
            [
            //  'adminhtml_customer_address',  //select if need
            //  'customer_address_edit',       //select if need
            //  'customer_register_address'    //select if need
            ]
    );
        $Attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    ?>
```

use above code in your script

Comment: Thanks nikhil, As we set 'used_in_forms', "is there any way to unset from forms" ?

Comment: I tried your way and the  above one also - but non making effect. Please check in updated question.

Comment: Above attribute currently showing in admin's customer form, but now I don't want.

Comment: Hi Please check update code

Comment: its giving this error -  [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]                                                
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update   
  a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`csep`.`eav_attribute`, CONSTR  
  AINT `EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTITY_TYPE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN   
  KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON D  
  ELETE CASCAD), query was: INSERT INTO `eav_attribute` () VALUES ()

Comment: In my case, `required` doesn't work, but `is_required` works.

Answer (score 3):

```
 public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.5', '<')) {
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                'lastname',
                [
                    'required' => false
                ]
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this worked for me:

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.9', '<')) {
    $customerSetup->updateAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'your_attribute_id', ['required' => true]);
}
```