# Magento2:How to updated customer attribute programmatically?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I am using magento2. I have created customer custom attribute in magento2.I want to change labels of created customer custom attribute. i have created two files installData.php and upgradeData.php in setup folder. but not changing the labels of custom attribute.also i am confusing between InstallData and UpgradeData files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go throught the below link you need to use install data for first time while you are upgrading module from than you need to use upgrade data go  through below link you will get idea to update the customer attribute programatically.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/223329/66936