# Add Custom Validation Street Address Field in backend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, backend, validation, address-attribute, custom-validation

> **I Want To Set Minimum Length Value For Street Address Field On Admin Side**

[image]

I want to set **`min_text_length = 5`** For **`Street Address`** Field In Customer Address Form

> **I am Trying To Update Attribute but Not Working**

```
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetup->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                'customer_address',
                'street',
                [
                    'type' => 'static',
                    'label' => 'Street Address',
                    'input' => 'multiline',
                    'backend' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\DefaultBackend::class,
                    'sort_order' => 70,
                    'multiline_count' => 4,
                    'validate_rules' => '{"max_text_length":255,"min_text_length":5}',
                    'position' => 70,
                ]
            );
        }
    }
```

**In Database Already Set `{"max_text_length":255,"min_text_length":5}` But Validation not Working**

[image]

**Note :- Admin Side Not Frontend Side.**

Comment: you can update attribute and add validation by setup script(can add manually from DB),For front checkout remove validation by changing LayoutProcessor.php and do same thing in register and update address section by removing validation class

Comment: i know about address form and checkout page but in admin side not find any reference or solution

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: v 2.2.8 @Sohel Rana

Comment: Please post your code/ mention clearly which form you want to customize in question.

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: Go to Customer setting ->Name and address option set Number of Lines in a Street Address to 5 after removing the validation class

Comment: this configuration for display number of line of street field

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You Can do it by [Script](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163045/magento-2-upgrade-existing-custom-customer-attribute#answer-163053) and update validation within it.You have to change

```
'validate_rules' => '{"max_text_length":255,"min_text_length":5}',
```

You can change it directly from DB you have to do it carefully.

- Open table `eav_attribute` and find `attribute_code` street and get
  `attribute_id` from it (generally attribute_id is 28).

[image]

- Open table `customer_eav_attribute` and find that `attribute_id` (28
  in my case). update in `validate_rules` column
  `{"max_text_length":255,"min_text_length":5}`

[image]

- Now it is done in admin

  [image]

**Note:** You have to remove if it occurs in front

Comment: let me check and replay soon

Comment: no bro its not working i have already try to update attribute

Comment: but in data base already set {"max_text_length":255,"min_text_length":5} but validation is not working

Comment: 1+ for response

Comment: may any other extension conflicts or js error,otherwise you can check it working for me

Comment: no i m check and also try in fresh setup but not working in admin side

Comment: Not possible, it must work it's default behavior,let's check by Team viewer

Answer (score 5):

**i am not sure if this works**

```
<rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
```

**Example from first name**

```
<field name="city" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
```

**remove this validation**

```
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
```

**up to here**

```
            <dataType>text</dataType>
        </settings>
    </field>
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: @RkRathod hi sorry i thought you wanted to remove the validation. i will let you know if i find something. sorry again

Comment: @RkRathod try this :
        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">5</item>

Comment: @RkRathod did it work? or was it something new you found

Comment: @RkRathod  if you dont mind will you share the answer?

Comment: solution work for city field not street address

Comment: @RkRathod take a look at this link, not sure would this help but he applied for shipping address in xml file
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150982/magento-2-form-validation-minimum-maximum-length/150984#150984

Answer (score 1):

update column validate_rules = {"min_text_length":"1","max_text_length":"10","input_validation":"length"} in table customer_eav_attribute with attribute_id = 28.
it's working for me for first fied in address
[image]

Step 2: In ui_component/customer_address_form.xml
[image]

Step 3: Create Observer
[image]

[image]

Step 4: override file Magento\Customer\Model\Address\DataProvider.php
[image]

[image]

Comment: it's worked. thanks.

Comment: because the first validate rules updated in db is worked for the first street view only, and not worked for 2 last street view, so the idea is create 2 new dummy fields and hide 2 last street fields. then when we save the 2 new dummy field, we will set 2 last street fields by that 2 dummy field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the admin (Magento 2.3.3):

[image: Admin address validation]

Comment: Where can i find this in admin?

Comment: @Nayem Stores -> Attributes -> Customer Address, and select "Street Address" from the list.

Comment: It looks like Adobe have removed access to editing customer attributes from 2.4.x Community/Open Source edition.  Adobe Commerce only :(

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/attributes-customer.html