# Magento 2.3.2 Address How to Remove City Field

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, magento2.3.2, city

I am using the Magento 2.3.2.

I want to remove "**City**" field into the checkout.

I have added the following code into my theme **checkout_index_index.xml** file:

```
<item name="city" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
```

The **City** field is not displaying But when I am Placing the order then following error occured:

> Please check the shipping address information. "city" is required. Enter and try again.

Can you please tell me how to remove the city field into the checkout without error when placing an order.

Thanks

Comment: Why not give the city a default value when saving it on the backend, such as placeholder, so that you can verify it correctly with magento without changing the code.

Comment: Hello @tokey, Nice Idea.Can you please tell me How to set CIty default value.

Comment: you can preference Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\SaveOrder,or use sales_order_save_before event save custom city default value.

Comment: Not working it throws the error first City is required because I think it is checked validation via the jquery

Answer (score 4):

[Remove Postcode from Checkout](http://serbu.me/2016/10/01/how-to-remove-postcode-field-from-magento2-checkout/)

> **Beacuse the php validation return false, inside class `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address` you will find validate function
>   :**

**First create the `di.xml` inisde you extension directly in folder etc `YourVendor/YourExtName/etc/di.xml`  and fill :**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address" type="YourVendor\YourExtName\Model\Quote\Address" />
</config>
```

**Now create the class  Address inside `YourVendor/YourExtName/Model/Qoute/Adress`,php and push :**

```
<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourExtName\Model\Quote;
class Address extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address
{
   /**
     * Validate address attribute values
     *
     * @return bool|array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function validate()
    {
        $errors = [];
        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getFirstname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter the first name.');
        }
       if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getLastname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter the last name.');
        }
        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getStreetLine(1), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter the street.');
        }
         if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getCity(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            //$errors[] = __('Please enter the city.');
        }
        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getTelephone(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter the phone number.');
        }
        $_havingOptionalZip = $this->_directoryData->getCountriesWithOptionalZip();
        if (!in_array(
            $this->getCountryId(),
            $_havingOptionalZip
        ) && !\Zend_Validate::is(
            $this->getPostcode(),
            'NotEmpty'
        )
        ) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter the zip/postal code.');
        }
         if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getCountryId(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter the country.');
        }
        if ($this->getCountryModel()->getRegionCollection()->getSize() && !\Zend_Validate::is(
            $this->getRegionId(),
            'NotEmpty'
        ) && $this->_directoryData->isRegionRequired(
            $this->getCountryId()
        )
        ) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter the state/province.');
        }
       if (empty($errors) || $this->getShouldIgnoreValidation()) {
            return true;
        }
        return $errors;
      }
}
```

> **commented the code related to city field**

```
if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getCity(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            //$errors[] = __('Please enter the city.');
        }
```

**Update :-**

> **Execute This Query in Database :-**

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'city' ORDER BY `attribute_id` DESC
```

And Check `is_requred` is **0** or **1**

**If 1 Than Change And Try**

Comment: when the customer is logged in then not working.for guest only working

Comment: try to clean cache and static content deploy

Comment: Yes, I have do this step

Comment: thnk q....@Abdul Pathan :)

Comment: Hello @RkRathod, I have tried many times but it is not working for a Logged in users. The city is required field error occurred. It is working great for the guest user.

Comment: you can set directly in database... check my updated answer

Comment: I have removed the require field into the DB still same error occurs.I have checked with content:deploy.I think this is handle via the knockout js

Comment: no i have same issue for street field check my question https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/278392/72911

Comment: Not worked bro..

Comment: issue solved or not ?

Comment: please check added link in answer

Comment: this artical for remove postcode you can modify for city field

Answer (score 2):

Try changing xml to

```
<item name="city" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
  <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
   </item>
</item>
```

Comment: Same error occured